# Proof of quantum correlation functions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, correlation-functions, time-evolution

I'm reading through David Tong's lecture notes on QFT.

On pages 76-77, he gives a proof about correlation functions.  See the below link:

[QFT notes by Tong](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf)

I'm following the proof steps to obtain equation (3.95). But several intermediate steps of the proof are not clear.

**First question**

Why can we write

$$T\phi_{1I} \dots \phi_{nI}S=U_{I}(+\infty, t_{1})\phi_{1I}U(t_{1},t_{2})\phi_{2I}\dots \phi_{nI}U_{I}(t_{n},-\infty)\ \ ?$$

I mean, after dropping the $T$, shouldn't we have

$$=\phi_{1I}\phi_{2I}\dots \phi_{nI}S$$$$=\phi_{1I}\phi_{2I}\dots \phi_{nI}U_{I}(+\infty,-\infty)\ \ ?$$

Does $T$ relate to the $\phi_{1}\dots\phi_{n}$ only, or to the $\phi_{1}\dots \phi_{nI}S$ and
$$U_{I}(+\infty,-\infty)=U_{I}(+\infty, t_{1})U_{I}(t_{1},t_{2})\dots U_{I}(t_{n},-\infty)\ \ ?$$

**Second question**

How do we convert each of the $\phi_{I}$ into $\phi_{H}$ using
$$U_{I}(t_{k},t_{k+1})=Texp(-i\int_{t_{k}}^{t_{k+1}}H_{I})$$
to arrive at

$$T\phi_{1I} \dots \phi_{nI}S=U_{I}(+\infty, t_{0})\phi_{1H}\dots \phi_{nH}U_{I}(t_{0},-\infty)\ \ ?$$

**Third question**

Why do we have

$$U_{I}(t, -\infty)=U(t,-\infty)\ \ ?$$

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2041503/11127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First question**

Using that $S=U_I(+\infty,-\infty)=U_I(+\infty, t_1)U_I(t_1,t_2)\cdots U_I(t_n,-\infty)$, as you state, you have that
\begin{align}
T\phi_{1I}\phi_{2I}\cdots\phi_{nI}S &= 
T\phi_{1I}\phi_{2I}\cdots\phi_{nI}
U_I(+\infty, t_1)U_I(t_1,t_2)\cdots U_I(t_n,-\infty) \\
& =
U_I(+\infty, t_1)\phi_{1I}U_I(t_1,t_2)\phi_{2I}\cdots
\phi_{nI}U_I(t_n,-\infty),
\end{align}
where the second equality is given by the definition of time ordering.

**Second question**

Choosing the operators in the interaction picture and the Heisenberg picture to be equal at some time $t_0$, we have that $\phi_{kI}=U(t_0,t_k)^{-1}\phi_{kH}U_I(t_0,t_k)$. Subtituting into the result for the previous question:
\begin{align}
T\phi_{1I}\phi_{2I}\cdots\phi_{nI}S =&
U_I(+\infty, t_1)U(t_0,t_1)^{-1}\phi_{1H}U_I(t_0,t_1)
U_I(t_1,t_2) U(t_0,t_2)^{-1}\\
& \phi_{2H}U_I(t_0,t_2)
\cdots
U(t_0,t_n)^{-1}\phi_{nH}U_I(t_0,t_n)U_I(t_n,-\infty) \\
=& U_I(+\infty,t_0)\phi_{1H}\phi_{2H}\cdots\phi_{nH}U_I(t_0,-\infty)
\end{align}

**Third question**

Notice that Tong is not saying that $U_I(t,-\infty)=U(t,-\infty)$, but
that for any $\left|\Psi\right>$, we have $\left<\Psi\right| U_I(t,-\infty)\left|0\right>=\left<\Psi\right|U(t,-\infty)\left|0\right>$. This statement is equivalent to 
\begin{equation}
U_I(t,-\infty)\left|0\right>=U(t,-\infty)\left|0\right>
\end{equation}
By definition $\left|0\right>$ is an eigenvector of $H_0$ with eigenvalue $0$, so
\begin{equation}
H_I\left|0\right>=H_Ie^{iH_0t}\left|0\right>=H_I\left|0\right>_I=
i\frac{d}{dt}\left|0\right>_I=
i\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{iH_0t}\left|0\right>\right)=
i\frac{d}{dt}\left|0\right>=H\left|0\right>.
\end{equation}
Thus, the interaction picture time evolution $U_I(t,-\infty)$ (obtained by exponentiating the integral of $H_I$) and the Schrödinger picture time evolution $U(t,-\infty)$ (the exponential of the integral of $H$) are the same when applied to $\left|0\right>$.

Comment: I'd like to point out that your first and second equations are *way* non-trivial (unlike what you might seem to suggest). For one thing, the definition of $T$ for coinciding time arguments has many subtleties. Moreover, you cannot use $U(t_1,t_2)U(t_2,t_3)=U(t_1,t_3)$ inside the $T$ symbol (at least, not without the proper justification by analysing the different permutations and so on).

Comment: Hmm... maybe I'm being too naive here. I tried to explain the ideas in the proof text in the reference (which says even less). I hope that my answer shows the path, but maybe it should've been much more detailed. I think I'll add a little paragraph a the beginning explaining this.

Comment: What you wrote is rather standard: you can find the very same (IMHO, naive) treatment in most introductory books on QFT. In this sense, your post is ok as far as Im concerned, but I just wanted to point out that, strictly speaking, matters are not so simple if one wants to formalise the theory.

Comment: You're right. I'll leave it as it is and let the people know about those subtleties by reading your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Are you discussing here how to time order $\phi_{1I}U_I(t_1,t_2)$ or $U_I(t_1,t_2)\phi_{1I}$?

Comment: @VictorVMotti I think that by "the definition of $T$ for coinciding time arguments has many subtleties" AccidentalFourierTransform means that kind of problems.  Handwaving, I would say that the operators $H_I$ that appear in the integrals inside $U_I(t_1,t_2)$ are evaluated at times between $t_1$ and $t_2$ and therefore they should be to the right of $\phi_{1I}$.

Comment: @coconut. I see, thanks a lot. By the way, where in your answer did you use the equation by Tong as given in my question text: $U_{I}(t_{k},t_{k+1})=Texp(-i\int_{t_{k}}^{t_{k+1}}H_{I})$?